# A set is recursively enumerable iff it is the range of a total recursive function

Tags: logic, computability

A set is called recursively enumerable if it is the domain of a partially recursive function.

How can I show that this definition are equivalent to "A set is recursively enumerable iff it is the range of a total recursive function"?

I could only show one direction: if a set is the range of a total recursive function $f$, then it is the domain of a partial recursive function, by defining a function $g$, on input $y$, look for an $x$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: How do you define "recursive", is it $\mu$-recursive, or some other schemata of construction, or is it by logical complexity of the definition?

Comment: You mean *nonempty* set don't you? The empty set is r.e. but is not the range of a total recursive function.

Comment: Informally: Suppose a nonempty set $A$ is the domain of a partial recursive function $g.$ Choose $a\in A.$ Start computing $g(x)$ for all $x,$ one step at a time. If step $n$ of the big computation is the last step in the computation of $g(x),$ define $f(n)=x;$ if step $n$ is not the last step in the computation of any value of $g,$ define $f(n)=a.$ Then $f$ is a total recursive function whose range is $A.$

Comment: Is your text actually defining recursively enumerable as being the domain of a partial recursive function?

Comment: @DanielV yes indeed.

Comment: @bof So your function $f$ takes $n$ as an input, output $a$ (which is in $A$) if $g$ does not halt on $x$ in the nth step, and output $x$ otherwise?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "$g$ does not halt on $x$ in the $n$th step". I'm thinking of a process which is working on all values of $g$ at once: We do the first step in the calculation of $g(1),$ then the first step in calculating $g(2),$ then the second step in calculating $g(1),$ then the first step for $g(3),$ and so on. The input $n$ refers to the number of steps of this overall process that have been carried out. The output is either the value of $x$ such that the calculation of $g(x)$ has just terminated, or else $a.$

Comment: @SidCaroline Are you familiar with how $\mathbb N^2$ is constructively isomophric to $\mathbb N$ ?  Like if I said "there is a bijection between fractions and natural numbers" is that something you are familiar with?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are having difficulty somewhere with converting the informal short sketch into a fully detailed sketch.

So let's try to see in detail how a (non-empty) set being r.e. (recursively enumerable) implies that it is the range of some total recursive function.

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ be a non-empty r.e. set. Then, by definition, there exists a partial recursive function $f_A:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$f_A(x)=1 \quad if \, x\in A$$
$$f_A(x)=\,\uparrow \qquad if \, x\notin A$$

We want to construct a (total) recursive function $g:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$range(g)=A$$
Let's divide into two cases:

**(1)** A has infinite number of elements

In that case define a function such as $step:\mathbb{N}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that $step(i,t,x)$ returns $1$ if a program corresponding to index $i$ halts(when given the input $x$) exactly at step $t$ -- and $0$ otherwise.

Note that since the function $f_A$ described above is partial recursive, there exists some program that computes it. The variable $x$ below is supposed to be given as input to the function $g$. Here is how we proceed with constructing the function $g(x)$:

> $i:=index\;of\;some\;program\;that\;computes\;f_A \\ n:=0 \\ m:=0 \\ while(n\neq x+1) \,\,\{ \\   a:=first(m) \\  b:=second(m) \\ \qquad if(step(i,a,b)=1) \,\,\{ \\ \qquad \,\, n:=n+1\\ \qquad \,\,y:=b  \\ \qquad \} \\  m:=m+1  \\ \} \\ return \;\; y
> $

For the functions $first:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and $second:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function. To define them rigorously consider any computable bijective function $pair:\mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. Define:
$$first(x)=\{\,a\in\mathbb{N} : \exists b\in \mathbb{N} \, (pair(a,b)=x)  \}$$
$$second(x)=\{\,b\in\mathbb{N} : \exists a\in \mathbb{N} \, (pair(a,b)=x)  \}$$
I think these definitions should be OK (but I am not fully confident). Anyway, note that the main properties of these functions are that for all $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ we have:
$$first(pair(a,b))=a$$
$$second(pair(a,b))=b$$

**(2)** A has finite number of elements

Suppose the number of elements in A are $N$. Then we can write A (without repetition) as:
$$A=\{a_0,\,a_1,....,a_{N-1}\}$$

Now define:

$g(x)=a_{x} \qquad for \; 0\leq x \leq N-1 \\
g(x)=a_{N-1} \qquad for \; x \geq N$

**P.S.**

The above method in case(1) doesn't repeat the elements of A (in the range of g) when it is infinite.

The method that is described in comments below the question is a little different and removes the need of having a separate case for finite number of elements.  Suppose $e\in A$. Here is a sketch for calculating $g(x)$ using that method:

> $i:=index\;of\;some\;program\;that\;computes\;f_A \\ e:=some\;element\;that\;belongs\;to\;A \\ a:=first(x) \\  b:=second(x) \\ if(step(i,a,b)=1) \,\,\{ \\  y:=b  \\ \} \\ if(step(i,a,b)=0) \,\,\{ \\ \\ y:=e \\ \} \\ return \;\; y
> $

Comment: It would be good to insert the purpose of the function $g$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use @SSequence's notations, whose nice answer led me to this.

$step$ is the (totally recursive) function $step:\mathbb{N}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ that returns $1$ if a program corresponding to index $i$ halts(when given the input $x$) exactly at step $t$ -- and $0$ otherwise.

Let $A \neq \emptyset$ be your r.e set (finite or infinite), and $f$ a partially recursive function whose domain is $A$. Say $f$ is computed by a program whose index is $i$.

Let $a$ be the minimum of $A$.

First, we define a totally recursive function $g$ that, with input $n$, returns the pair made of a number $l$ (the number of hits) and a $l$-tuple consisting of all the $x \leqslant n$ that were accepted by $f$ in up to $n$ steps and $a$ (eventually, $a$ will appear twice).

> **definition of $g(n)$**
> $tup:=a$
> $l := 1$
> For $t:=0$ to $n$ do:
> $\qquad$For $x:=0$ to $n$ do:
> $\qquad$$\qquad$If $step(i, t, x)$ == $1$:
> $\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$tup:=Pair(tup, x)$
> $\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$$l := l + 1$
> Return $Pair(l, tup)$

**Unpacking this result**
Say we have computed $g(n)$. The length of the tuple $tup:=second(g(n))$ is $l := first(g(n))$. We can pop the last element (let's call him $x$) of tup like this :

> **definition of $pop(l, tup)$**
> """$tup$ and $l$ are global variables"""
> If $l==0$:
> $\qquad$ $l:= l - 1$
> $\qquad$ Return $tup$
> Else:
> $\qquad$ $l:= l - 1$
> $\qquad$ $x := second(tup)$
> $\qquad$ $tup := first(tup)$
> $\qquad$ Return $x$

This can be done while $l\geqslant 0$ to recover, from the last to the first, the hits packed in $g(n)$.

Now that $g$ and $pop$ are defined, we can define the following totally recursive function $h$ whose range is $A$:

> $h(0) = a$
> For $m>0$, $h(m)$ is the smallest element from $g(m)$ (to be unpacked as above) that wasn't already returned by $h(0), \dots, h(m-1)$ if there is one, or $a$ otherwise.

The construction of $h$ can be achieved by primitive recursion.